# How to create a list in python?

Tags: python, list, attributes

I want to create a list in python named "p_spaces" which will have 20 elements. Every element will have an id and and two other attributes. The first attribute is "initial state" and will be either "free" or "occupied" with probability 1/2 and the second attribute will be state and will be at first empty.

I would like to create it dynamically. For example "for i in range(19)"

Could someone help me?

Comment: Maybe a list of dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initial_state = ['free', 'occupied']
state = ''
p_spaces = []
for i in range(20):
    p_spaces.append({i: [initial_state[i % 2], state]})
print(p_spaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list of dictionaries:

```py
p_spaces = [ {"id": 0, "initial_state": "free", "state": None} ...]
```

On a side note, if `initial_state` is a binary choice, you might as well use 0/1 or True/False.

You could create it dynamically:

```py
for i in range(20):
    p_spaces.append({"id":i,
                    "intial_state": "free", #or occupied
                    "state" : None})
```

To edit any element:

```py
p_spaces[item_number][attribute_name] = new_value
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would like to create it dynamically. For example: fro i in range(19)

Comment: @ana check my edit. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but is this something that you were meaning?

```
class Something:
   def __init__(self, id=0, initial_state = "free", state="empty"):
      self.id = id
      self.initial_state = initial_state
      self.state = state
   
   def SetState(self, state):
      self.state = state

   def SetId(self, id):
      self.id = id
   
   def GetId(self):
      return self.id

   def GetState(self):
      return self.state
 
   def GetInitialState(self):
      return self.initial_state
   


def PrintList(lst):
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        print(lst[i].GetId(), lst[i].GetInitialState(), lst[i].GetState())


n = 20
p_spaces = [None]*n
for i in range(0, n):
    sth_var = Something()
    p_spaces[i] = sth_var


PrintList(p_spaces)
```

Comment: And how can I print the whole list?